# Visual Studio #ifdef #elif for product id's

Tags: visual-studio, syntax, syntax-error, directive

so I'm using 1 solution for multiple products and I need to make some kind of 'product id system' so i know what product people are using.

HEre is my attempt:

```
    #ifdef _WIN64
            #if defined(_DEBUG)
                    #if defined(PFW_APP_D3D_TEST)
                        #define PFW_PRODUCT_ID 1
                    #elif defined(PFW_APP_LOADER)
                        #define PFW_PRODUCT_ID 24
                    #endif
            #else
                    #if defined(PFW_APP_D3D_TEST)
                        #define PFW_PRODUCT_ID 25
                    #elif defined(PFW_APP_LOADER)
                        #define PFW_PRODUCT_ID 48
                        //Then some nested #if here
                    #endif
            #endif
    #else
            #if defined(_DEBUG)
                    #if defined(PFW_APP_D3D_TEST)
                        #define PFW_PRODUCT_ID 49
                    #elif defined(PFW_APP_LOADER)
                        #define PFW_PRODUCT_ID 72
                    #endif

            #else
                    #if defined(PFW_APP_D3D_TEST)
                        #define PFW_PRODUCT_ID 73
                    #elif defined(PFW_APP_LOADER)
                        #define PFW_PRODUCT_ID 96
                    #endif

            #endif
    #endif
```

but it doesn't compile D: (no clue how to properly use this # system

[image: Proof of error]

so my question is, how can i fix the syntax error and is there a automated way i can generate product id's?

Comment: Post code as text (code block), not as a screenshot. And we need a complete code, as the error refers to "end-of-file".

Comment: it's just the syntax error, it was visible in the screenshot, i posted some code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem fixed...

changed from

```
            #elif defined(PFW_APP_BF1)
                #if defined(PFW_GAME_BF4)
                    #define PFW_PRODUCT_ID 51
                #elif defined(PFW_GAME_BF1)
                    #define PFW_PRODUCT_ID 52
```

to

```
            #elif defined(PFW_APP_BF1)
                #elif defined(PFW_GAME_BF4)
                    #define PFW_PRODUCT_ID 51
                #elif defined(PFW_GAME_BF1)
                    #define PFW_PRODUCT_ID 52
```

but sad that i couldn't use #if :D